# Need Sample data for Magento1.5

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, sample-data

I need sample data for Magento ver-1.5.1.0. I didn't found in Magentocommerce site. Kindly let me know where we get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-sample-data-archive-for-magento-1019870).

The link leads to a page where you can download sample data.
The page contains two links to updated sample data for newer Magento version, as well as informations on how to deal with them.

Comment: follow the links, you'll get full explanation

Answer (score 1):

The correct sample data is available at the normal download process through magento website.

When you select your version and the file format (.tar, .zip, etc) and click on download button, on the next page you have a link to download the correct version of sample data, test framework, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit old but hope this answer will be useful for others too.

This is the latest sample data matching your version - http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.2.0/magento-sample-data-1.2.0.tar.gz

Note it will take some time to install Magento over this sample data due to significant DB structure changes since 1.2.

The next sample data update was 1.6.1.0 (http://www.magentocommerce.com/getmagento/1.6.1.0/magento-sample-data-1.6.1.0.zip) but it won't work with Magento 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You need sample data version 1.2.0 for Magento 1.5.1.0

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-sample-data-archive-for-magento-120

Answer (score 0):

I could get files on following link,

http://mirror.gunah.eu/magento/sample-data/

it has following sample data files,

magento-sample-data-1.1.2.
magento-sample-data-1.6.1.0
magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0
magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0